# Counter program not working Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, counter

I want to make a times table machine that gets a certain amount, adds the amount, says what the sum is and ask if you want to carry on via Y/n.

I type 'n' to carry on but it for some reason stops?

Can someone help me

Here is my code:

```
print('''Welcome to loop, here, you shall be able to experience you multiples up to a certain amount
e.g my multiples of 9s.''')
p=input('Increasing in? ')
a=0
b=1
while True:
    a+=int(p)
    print(str(a)+', this is '+str(p)+'*' + str(b))
    b+=1
    s=input('Stop? [Y/n] ONLY! ')
    if s.lower() or s.upper() == 'y'
        print('Thank you for using loop, See you again soon. ')
        break
    elif s.lower() or upper() == 'n':
        pass
```

Comment: Just FYI, I added a missing tag "python-3.x" - this will make your question easier to find by people interested in the subject. General advice is to always tag with languages and/or systems + their versions if relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found small mistake in your code after capturing user input i.e. Y/n the if condition seems like wrong.
The below code should work for your requirements

```
def test():
  p = input("Increasing in")
  a = 0
  b = 1
while True:
  a += int(p)
  print(str(a) + ', this is ' + str(p) + '*' + str(b))
  b += 1
  s = input('Stop [Y/n] ONLY! ')
  if(s == 'y' or s.lower() == 'y'):
    print('Thank you for using loop')
    break
  else:
    pass
test()
```

Comment: I think `if(s.lower() == 'y')` would even be sufficient here.